# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getRow' extjs4

Tags: extjs4

I'm getting the error - has no method 'getRow'.

Here is the code snippet:

var g = this.grid, view = g.getView(),
 row = view.getRow(rowIndex),

The same was working fine in extjs3 and not working in extjs4.

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Rahul.

Comment: This is working fine:  view.getNode(rowIndex)

Answer (score 0):

In Ext 4 [`Ext.view.Table`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.view.Table) has no `getRow()` method.

You can use [`getNode()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-method-getNode) instead, and wrap in with `Ext.get()` if you need an `Ext.Element` and not a `HTMLElement`.